# "Nonetype" error while being assigned to variables

Tags: python, variables

Just started my Programming 1 class, and we were assigned to create a quiz, and tally up the final score at the end. As a result I created this simple statement to play after every question.

```
if answer_1 == correct_1:
    a1 = 1 and print("You are correct!")
else:
    a1 = 0 and print("You are incorrect.")
```

However, at the end it is telling me I cannot add an integer and a NoneType. The wrong answers (zeroes) are being applied fine, it's when the answer is right that it gets stored as a NoneType (which I  know means nothing). I'm aware I'm doing some syntax wrong, but do not quite have the know how to fix it.

Comment: Get rid of the `and` and start a new line for the `print` on the same level of indentation

Answer (score 1):

You are stuck with couple of things here:

1. you got precedence wrong since here `and` will be evaluated first, then `=`
2. `print` returns `None`, and `1 and None = None`, while `0 and None = 0`.

Here is a solution:

```
if answer_1 == correct_1:
    a1 = 1 
    print("You are correct!")
else:
    a1 = 0
    print("You are incorrect.")
```

**Edit:**

Just wanted to point out why it stands that `1 and None = None` and `0 and None = 0`.

It is because Python evaluates boolean conditions lazily.

Here is what [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) say about it:

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.
>
> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

---

#### Just for science

Having lazy evaluation of boolean conditions and `=` precedence you can mimic conditional (ternary) operator, construct you might find in other languages.

> **Definition of ternary operator:** `condition ? expr1 : expr2`.
>
> **Explanation:** If `condition` is true, the operator returns the value of
>   `expr1`; otherwise, it returns the value of `expr2`.

In Python, you can mimic this with: `condition and expr1 or expr2`.

Same applies as with definition of ternary operator. If `contition` evaluates to `True`, `expr1` is returned. Otherwise, `expr2` is returned.

**Why I said just for science? Because although this looks great, it's not used often and may affect readability of your code.**

Answer (score 0):

Python’s `and` is a logical operator.  It takes two values (either side) and returns `True` or `False`.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's homework, I'll give you a strong hint.  `and` doesn't work the way you're thinking here. You can have more than one line within an `if` statement.